# how can I authenticate to a rest web service by ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to send username and password to a Rest web service to recover the Token. I tested this code but always sends me  to error function

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "http://192.168.1.89:1111/connect/token",
  dataType: 'json',
  async: false,
  data: '{}',
  beforeSend: function(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', btoa(username, password));
  },
  success: function() {
    alert('Thanks for your comment!');
  },
  error: function(xhr, status, error) {
    alert(error);
  }
});
```

Comment: `btoa()` accepts only a single argument. You most likely need to concatenate the `username` and `password` together somehow, and prefix the result with the word `Basic`. Check the API documentation for more details.

Comment: Also, remove `async: false`. It's terrible practice and you don't need to use it anyway as you're using the callbacks properly already.

Comment: thank you @RoryMcCrossan for your comment , i update my code  beforeSend: function (xhr) {
 xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password));
 },   But still redirect me to the error function

Comment: Try xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic " + window.btoa(username + ":" + password)); }

Comment: I tried window.btoa but still the same problem, Note I tried to send username and password by a POST url 'http://192.168.1.89:1111/connect/token' via the extension FireFox RestClient but it sends me: BadRequest (The link shown in the code is a fake link for security reasons)